# How can you remove or disable some US states from showing up in profile?

Tags: profile, localisation

How can you remove or disable some states from showing up in profile?

We really only want a few showing up - Latest CiviCRM - not using webform - this is for profiles.

Comment: Show only few on profiles?

Comment: Yes, we don't need states like: United States Minor Outlying Islands, etc

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show only few US states across whole CiviCRM form than you can set civicrm_state_province.is_active = 0 for the ones to not show for country_id = 1228